# How to write a grok pattern for the time format 01/27/2015 09:32:44 AM

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

How to write a grok pattern for the time format 01/27/2015 09:32:44 AM 
I tried %{DATESTAMP:timestamp} but its not taking AM in it, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a custom pattern file for yourself. As describe in [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok)

From my experience, in the pattern file, create this pattern

```
DATESTAMP_12HOUR %{DATESTAMP} (AM|PM)
```

Then, when you use `grok` plugin and specific your customs patterns directory.

```
filter{
    grok {
            patterns_dir => "./patterns"
            match => [
                    "message","%{DATETIME_12HOUR:msgTime}"

            ]
    }
}
```